# Rails 3 polymorphic associations: scopes on the belongs_to side that reference the association are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have the following polymorphic associations:

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviteable, :polymorphic => true 

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, :as => :inviteable, :dependent => :destroy

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites, :as => :inviteable, :dependent => :destroy
```

I'm trying to create scopes on Invites specific to events, and to future events:

```
(in Invite.rb)
  scope :to_events, where('inviteable_type = ?', "Event")
  scope :to_future_events, lambda { self.to_events.joins("join events").where('events.starttime > ?', Time.now) }
```

The to_events scope works fine; the to_future_events returns the correct subset of invites, but it returns many copies of each.  Any idea why?  Is there a cleaner/Rails-ier way to accomplish what i'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are looking for the "Rails Way", you should probably change "Invite" to "Invitation" to clarify that the model is a noun, not a verb.  It will make your code read a little better, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide an ON statement for the join:

```
scope :to_future_events, lambda { self.to_events.joins("join events on events.id = invites.inviteable_id").where('events.starttime > ?', Time.now) }
```

Otherwise it joins every invite record with every events record.

Comment: That makes sense, though i'd also want some sort of inviteable_type == "Event" check, right?  There'd be occasional cases where inviteable_type == "team", inviteable_id happens to equal some event.id, and that event is in the future.  In that case i'd still get a dupe result, right?

Comment: Well, you're chaining it off of the `to_events` scope so it already has the `where('inviteable_type = ?', "Event")` condition.